# TypeScript compilation removes import and export

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

Here's my code.

```
// module1.ts
console.log("require module1");

import module2 from "./module2";
console.log(`module2 = ${module2}`);
```

```
// module2.ts
console.log("require module2");
export default "require module2";
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6"
  }
}
```

When I run `npx tsc module1.ts` it generates the following:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
console.log("require module1");
var module2_1 = require("./module2");
console.log("module2 = " + module2_1["default"]);
```

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
console.log("require module2");
exports["default"] = "require module2";
```

Is there a way to make the generated code use `import` and `export` instead of `requires` and `exports`? The behavior is different, i.e. `requires` runs inline and so `"require module2"` will be printed after `"require module1"`.

I don't actually have a use case for doing this. I'm just wondering if you can do it, and if you can't, why not.

Comment: Your target looks correct. You might have to check if your compiler references the correct config or not? Your output is obvious `commonjs` module which doesn't reflect with your config though

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [tmhao2005](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3104226/tmhao2005), you were right.

I should've read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html.

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

So, when I just run `npx tsc`, things get compiled as expected.